# How to integrate 2checkout with flutter

Tags: flutter, 2checkout

How to integrate 2checkout with flutter? is there any way to integrate 2checkout payment gateway with flutter app? can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Or how did you solve it if you did? I'm using flutter web and guessing I'm going to have to use and Iframe to connect to 2checkout

Comment: No, unfortunately did not find any way for this. I have started bounty for this question just now.

Comment: please do not forget to tell me if you found any way for this

Comment: After about 2 days of trying I decided to give up and use another payment gateway. I ended up using a similar implementation to this: https://itnext.io/flutter-web-razorpay-payment-gateway-integration-792d6e015409

Comment: now i am not in India, is it possible to use Razorpay out side of India

Comment: I don't know. I didn't use Razorpay but a South African gateway (I am from South Africa). I used the same method as used in the link for Razorpay for my chosen Gateway. Maybe try stripe if it's available in your country?

Comment: I am from turkey, and the stripe is not available in turkey. and i think razorpay is just available in india

Comment: and i don't know what should i do. what payment gateway do you use ???

Comment: I'm using a South African one called Yoco. Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable on payment gateways available in Turkey - best of luck.

Comment: If you do not have sdk-flutter available for this payment gateway, you can use sdk-android and use the (platform-channel)  feature  to connect to payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

When you need a package for Flutter, but it is not available, its native package (for example Android) and the creation of a channel by the platform-channel may help you to solve the problem.